# Problems performing an update on Cassandra having a compound partitioning key

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have this table in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE wear_dealer.product_color_size_stock (
    productcode text,
    colorcode text,
    sizecode text,
    ean text,
    shortdescription text,
    stock int,
    **PRIMARY KEY (productcode, colorcode, sizecode)**
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (colorcode ASC, sizecode ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX product_color_size_stock_stock_idx ON wear_dealer.product_color_size_stock (stock);
```

How can I update shortdescription having only the value for **productcode**

When I perform this query:

```
cqlsh:wear_dealer> update seasons_product_color_size
                   set shortdescription ='AAA'
                   where productcode='RUNTS';
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Some partition key parts are missing: seasoncode"
```

Any strategie to overcome this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So `update` command was run on the `seasons_product_color_size` table, but the description is for the `product_color_size_stock` table.  Unless the primary keys are the same, we'll need some more information here.

Comment: Sorry for that, the table should be the same. But in any case the output is the same

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CQL does not allow writes for a partial key.  Remember that Cassandra treats `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s the same.  So when this:

```
UPDATE seasons_product_color_size
SET shortdescription ='AAA'
WHERE productcode='RUNTS';
```

Returns this: `"Some partition key parts are missing: seasoncode"`

It's saying that Cassandra doesn't know which node to write the data to, because there isn't a partition key.  In SQL, it would just iterate through all rows in the table and update them according to your `WHERE` clause.  But Cassandra is specifically designed not to allow operations like that.

For this query you will need to figure out the missing `seasoncode`s separately, and `UPDATE` each row individually.

Comment: Just to add that specifying partition key in the filter is not enough, the whole primary key should be provided

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra supports write based on partition key, As you supplied partial partition key you cannot update with that.

```
UPDATE seasons_product_color_size SET shortdescription ='AAA' WHERE productcode='RUNTS' and sizecode=10
```

Comment: Even supplying all partition key would still require specifying filter on clustering keys